# React - Node component altering other Node content components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I was trying to create a grid of 10x10 that with every click on a button would render a different animal based on some logic.
Well It seems that I am doing something wrong because when I click it renders the animal but when I click another time and the new animal is different from the previous it alters it so the previous animal gets changed with the current new animal .
Here is the code

```
export class Grid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentFields: [],
      fieldsNotMarked: [],
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleRemovalOfFieldFromGrid =
      this.handleRemovalOfFieldFromGrid.bind(this);
  }
  generateGrid() {
    const array = [];
    for (let row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
      const currentRow = [];
      for (let col = 1; col <= 10; col++) {
        currentRow.push([]);
      }
      array.push(currentRow);
    }
    return array;
  }
  handleRemovalOfFieldFromGrid(fieldIdx) {
    const fieldsNotMarked = this.state.fieldsNotMarked;
    if (fieldsNotMarked.length === 0) {
      return;
    } else {
      const newFields = fieldsNotMarked.filter((idx) => idx !== fieldIdx);

      this.setState({ fieldsNotMarked: newFields });
    }
  }
  handleClick() {
    if (this.state.fieldsNotMarked.length === 0) {
      const newArrayOfAnimals = CurrentIdsNotMarked();
      this.setState({ fieldsNotMarked: newArrayOfAnimals });
    }

    setInterval(() => {
      const newAnimalId = getRandomId(this.state.currentFields);
      this.handleRemovalOfFieldFromGrid(newAnimalId);
      this.state.currentFields.push(newAnimalId);
      this.setState({
        currentFields: this.state.currentFields,
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
  render() {
    const grid = this.generateGrid();

    return (
      <div>
        {
          (console.log(this.state.currentFields),
          console.log(this.state.fieldsNotMarked))
        }
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Click
        </button>
        <div className="grid">
          {grid.map((row, rowIdx) => {
            return (
              <div key={rowIdx} className="row">
                {row.map((col, colIdx) => {
                  return (
                    <Node
                      key={colIdx}
                      id={`${rowIdx + 1}-${colIdx + 1}`}
                      currentFields={this.state.currentFields}
                      fieldsNotMarked={this.state.fieldsNotMarked}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function getRandomId(currentFields) {
  const array = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      array.push(`${i}-${j}`);
    }
  }
  const randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  const newId = array[randomIdx];
  return currentFields.includes(newId) ? getRandomId(currentFields) : newId;
}
function CurrentIdsNotMarked() {
  const array = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      array.push(`${i}-${j}`);
    }
  }
  return array;
}


export class Node extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.isCurrentIdInGrid = this.isCurrentIdInGrid.bind(this);
  }
  isCurrentIdInGrid(id) {
    const sheeps = this.props.currentFields;

    for (let i = 0; i < sheeps.length; i++) {
      if (sheeps[i] === id) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  handleAnimalState() {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      arr.push("sheep");
      if (i % 20 === 0) {
        arr.push("bear");
      }
      if (i % 10 === 0) {
        arr.push("wolf");
      }
    }
    const randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return arr[randomIdx];
  }
  isFieldIsNotMarkedAsAnimal(idx) {
    const fieldsNotMarked = this.props.fieldsNotMarked;
    for (let index in fieldsNotMarked) {
      if (fieldsNotMarked[index] === idx) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  render() {
    // We might have another function that decide whether we return a sheep, wolf or bear;
    let animalIfIdInGridAndIsNotMarked =
      this.isCurrentIdInGrid(this.props.id) &&
      !this.props.fieldsNotMarked.includes(this.props.id)
        ? this.handleAnimalState()
        : "";
    
    return <div className="node">{animalIfIdInGridAndIsNotMarked}</div>;
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OutDo.png)

Comment: "...when I click another time and the new animal is different from the previous it alters it so the previous animal gets changed with the current new animal" - I'm a little confused by this, can you be clear about how the grid is behaving when you click versus how you want it to behave?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Basically, every time I click I would like  a random animal to be generated and push it to the content of the node but in a different location of the grid. However, what currently happens is that when I click it generates a random animal (bear, wolf or sheep) and push to a random location in the grid BUT if this new animal is different from the previous somehow it override it. Apologies for the spaghetti code, I'm new to react